# Distributivity of Minkowski Sums

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does on prove the following distributive property:
$$S_1 + (S_2 \cup S_3) = (S_1 + S_2) \cup (S_1 + S_3),$$

where + means Minkowski sums.

---

I expanded the right hand side which gave me $$(S_1 \cup S_1) + (S_2 \cup S_1) + (S_1 \cup S_3) + (S_2 \cup S_3),$$ which gave me (maybe I'm wrong): $$S_1 + (S_2 \cup S_1) + (S_1 \cup S_3) + (S_2 \cup S_3).$$ I don't know what to do after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove first that $S_1 +(S_2 \cup S_3) \subseteq (S_1 + S_2)\cup (S_1 + S_3)$.

Let $x \in S_1 + (S_2 \cup S_3)$. By the definition of Minkovski sum there exist $y\in S_1,\ z \in S_2 \cup S_3 $ s.t. $x = y + z$.

If $z \in S_2$ then $x \in S_1 + S_2$. 
If $z \in S_3$ then $x \in S_1 + S_3$. Either way $x \in (S_1 + S_2)\cup (S_1 + S_3)$.

Then you should prove that $S_1 +(S_2 \cup S_3) \supseteq (S_1 + S_2)\cup (S_1 + S_3)$. There will be no surprises in this step,
it'll be similar to the previous direction.